# Java aplicação app

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Este código quando premido no botão `definicoes`, abre uma nova janela com uma imagem, uma linha com texto e também gera radio buttons, mas o problema é que cria outra nova janela com os radio buttons e além disso duplica o `JFrame` que contem todos os botões, e eu não quero duplicar o `JFrame`. O que eu queria era mostrar a imagem, o texto e os radio buttons todos na mesma nova janela. Tem como fazer isso? Mantendo claro e aberto o `JFrame` inicial que tem esse botão `definicoes` e tem também outros botões, etc.

```
 if (definicoesBtn == e.getSource()) // botao definicoes premido
 {
     window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Definicoes:");
     window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  

     JLabel label3 = new JLabel(" Definicoes: ");           
     window.add("Center", label3);
     window.resize(300,300);
     window.show();                         
     ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("definicoes.jpg");
     int altura = img.getIconHeight();  
     int largura = img.getIconWidth(); 
     JLabel label = new JLabel(img);    
     window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

     MemoryGame formulario1=new MemoryGame(); // cria os radiobutton
     formulario1.setBounds(0,0,300,200);
     formulario1.setVisible(true);

     window.pack();  
     window.setVisible(true); 
 }
```

A minha classe principal é esta logo nas primeiras linhas de código:

```
public class MemoryGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ChangeListener
{
    private JCheckBox check1,check2,check3; // declaracao dos checkbutoes
    //...  
    private JFrame window = new JFrame("Jogo da Memoria");
    // Jframe com todos os botoes janela inicial declarei em MemoryGame()

    public MemoryGame() {  
        setLayout(null);
        check1=new JCheckBox("Inglés");
        check1.setBounds(10,10,150,30);
        check1.addChangeListener(this);
        add(check1);
        check2=new JCheckBox("Francés");
        check2.setBounds(10,50,150,30);
        check2.addChangeListener(this);        
        add(check2);
        check3=new JCheckBox("Alemán");
        check3.setBounds(10,90,150,30);
        check3.addChangeListener(this);        
        add(check3);
```

E também a função:

```
 public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
    String cad="";
    if (check1.isSelected()==true) {
        cad=cad+"Inglés-";
    }
    if (check2.isSelected()==true) {
        cad=cad+"Francés-";
    }
    if (check3.isSelected()==true) {
        cad=cad+"Alemán-";
    }
    setTitle(cad);
}
```

Alguma coisa deve estar errada ou incompleta, por isso necessito de ajuda para resolver ou remediar o código.

Comment: Poste o código da classe completa, incluindo os imports. O seu erro é fácil de ver, você está instanciando novas `JFrame`s ao invés de usar a mesma. Mas para poder corrigir o seu problema, vou precisar de mais coisas que há na classe para saber o que colocar no lugar de criar uma nova janela. Ao menos uma classe compilável que mostre o problema já ajudaria bastante.

Comment: Já resolvi o problema.